# Map is not getting rendered while building an app using osmdroid

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am using Android Studio to build a simple OSM map application using osmdroid. I wish to display a map and then build a navigation system on top of that. I used [this](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_0) tutorial 0 of osmbonuspack.

Problem is the map is not getting rendered. I am attaching a ScreenShot of the emulator. Use this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17gAqmERmnU1_Siayhm8i5T6uKbHzUrUX/view) to see screenshot.

I am new to app development, I think I had a problem with `build.gradle` files. I tried syncing gradle with different versions, but no success. Also, I have included permission for every manifest file.

I am attaching code of my `build.gradle` file, `activitymain.java` file `AndroidManifest` and ScreenShot of Emulator.

I expect that after following tutorial0, a map with the marker would be rendered/displayed.

Thanks in advance.

**ActivityMain.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Configuration.getInstance().setUserAgentValue(getPackageName());



        MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        map.getZoomController();
        map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(48.13, -1.63);
        IMapController mapController = map.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(9.0);
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);

        map.invalidate();



        //for markers
        Marker startMarker = new Marker(map);
        startMarker.setPosition(startPoint);
        startMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
        map.getOverlays().add(startMarker);


        startMarker.setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

        startMarker.setTitle("Start point");

        map.invalidate();


    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'




   implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.0'
    implementation ( name: 'osmbonuspack_v6.6.0', ext:'aar')
}
```

**AndoidManifest**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp_6">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I would suggest to start with the documentation for the Osmdroid library itself: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki e.g.: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library since the basic stuff was moved from the osmbonuspack to the core librar. I am not sure how up to date the tutorial there is. Once you have basic things working, you can move to the more advanced stuff (routing/navigation).

Comment: The main difference is that the tutorial uses `Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));` to intialize everything before the layout is inflated. Other than that I don't see any obvious problem with the code you posted. But [check your logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat) for any errors, that might help to reveal any problems.